# Sheets Script - Detect duplicate cell in same column and remove newest row with duplicate cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I've looked around StackOverflow and also GitHub but I couldn't find a solution that seems to be simple enough. Here's the deal:

1. A form is used to input new clients into a sheet that contains all client details.
2. Accidentally, account managers sometimes "open" the same client twice (always using the same form which feeds to the same sheet).
3. I don't want to mess with the script of the actual form and I'm OK if the form will submit anyway, without checking anything prior to hitting the submit button.
4. After each submission, I run an onFormSubmit script. I want to use that script to detect such duplicate clients and delete the last entry, i.e. row with the most recent timestamp.
5. I understand that client name, addresses, and other string fields can sometimes enter with slight variations so my duplicate search will rely on the client ID number. Sure, typos can also happen with the ID but this is the safest option to detect duplicates.
6. Once removed, I'd like to send an email to a specific address (group). In the email, I'd like to list the ID number which was detected as a duplicate, along with the email of the user which inputted this duplicate, i.e. email of the last person to submit this duplicate. My form catches emails so they're logged into the Sheet anyway but that row will be deleted and I want to catch this email prior to deleting it with this script.

I don't have a sample code to place here as I couldn't find that was simple enough, or that hasn't fiddled with the actual form.
Any ideas for a simple yet effective script that only "touches" that single sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to believe I'm not the only super-novice here. For my fellow beginners, here's a simple code that uses a status-indicator cell to find a duplicate.

First, let's remember that the form is submitted either way, not checking anything on the form itself. here are some basic stups:
1. we sort the sheet by defending order of the timestamp column.
2. On cell Z2 I added the following function: *=match(F2,F3:F1000,0)*.
** In my case, column F holds the client ID, for which I want to search for duplicates.
4. Here's a simple code to wrap it up:

```
function searchduplicate () {
  var clientid = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("רשימת לקוחות").getRange('Z2').getValue();
  // var noduplicate = "N/A"
  if (clientid === "#N/A") {
    Logger.log("no duplicates")}
  // plus any other actions to run if no duplicates
  else {
    Logger.log("duplicate")}
  // plus any other actions to run if there ARE duplicates
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want but it does not allow rows to be append that have duplicate ClientID's and you can redefine what the client ID is and it get the rest of the headers from `e.named.Values`;  You can also position them in any order that you wish.

```
function dontAllowDuplicateClientIds(e) {
  const idhdr="ClientID";
  const hA=Object.keys(e.namedValues).filter(function(e){return e;});
  hA.splice(hA.indexOf('Timestamp'),1);
  Logger.log(hA);
  if(hA.indexOf(idhdr)==-1) {
    Logger.log("Invalid idhdr Assignment");
    return;
  }
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Non Duplicate Client Id Sheet2');
  if(!sh) {
    sh=ss.insertSheet('Non Duplicate Client Id Sheet2')
    sh.appendRow(hA)
  }
  const hdrA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  const idx={};
  const dA=[];
  hdrA.forEach(function(h,i){idx[h]=i;dA.push(e.namedValues[h][0]);});
  if(sh.getLastRow()>1) {
    const vA=sh.getRange(2,idx[idhdr]+1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(r,i){return r[0];});
    if(vA.indexOf(e.namedValues[idhdr][0])==-1) {
      sh.appendRow(dA)
    }
  }else{
    sh.appendRow(dA)
  }
  Logger.log(dA);
}
```

In you want to run this manually you can do so with this:

```
function testnextfunction() {
  var e={namedValues:{ClientID:"123abc",FirstName:'J',LastName:'Cooper',MiddleName:'B'}};
  dontAllowDuplicateClientIds(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper. Many thanks for your answer. I have to say that I don't fully follow your logic. Why do we need to use another sheet? again, many thanks and I mean no disrespect by my comment :)

Comment: I never change the linked sheet. I always leave alone to allow it to. Collect data.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure, did you include any deletion and/or notification elements in your code? I couldn't find them

Comment: I didn’t see the need it doesn’t append duplicates